# Can I use my iPhone charger with my iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, charging

My iPad 1 charger was burned because of high voltage, so it stopped working. Currently, I am using an iPhone 3GS mini charger. It charges the iPad but only very slowly when the iPad is on but the display is off.

- Will it make any problem if I continue using mini charger for charging my iPad 1 or do I need to buy a new charger?
- If yes, what is the price of new charger in India?

Comment: I suggest you get a new iPad charger, as the iPhone charger will charge, but very slowly (I left it charging this way overnight, and it still was only at 80% in the morning).

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can use your iPhone charger with the iPad.

This should not damage the iPad or the charger.

However, **since the iPad is provided with a lower current the charging takes longer**. Both the iPhone and iPad charge with **5V**, but the iPad charger provides **2A** while the iPhone charger only provides **1A**.

This is why it takes longer to charge. You should *completely turn off the iPad* in order to speed up the charging process.

Comment: it will not harm my battery life of my ipad please tell

Comment: @vitthal I'm not sure. The answer depends on the type of battery. Apple uses Li-Poly batteries. Fact is: 1) Apple does not list the iPad as ["supported" by the iPhone charger](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB352LL/C) 2) [Users report](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MC359LL/A?pqid=QYCDTATUXJCXYUJKJATYY4CK7XHD42UHJ) that this works fine.

Comment: I can confirm the answer of gentmatt. I've charged both my iPad and iPhone with all the chargers (both iPad and iPhone). It charges in both cases but the one with the most A, charges faster.

Comment: Apple chargers contain complex over-current and over-voltage protections as well as circuitry that put the charger into a low power trickle charge once charging is complete.

Answer (score 8):

The 5W, 10W and 12W chargers are all capable of charging an iPhone. The wattage is made up of two variables - voltage and ampage (or amperage if you're American). The wattage also states the MAXIMUM output of the power block.

All three chargers have the same voltage output (5V), the difference comes with the amp output (1A, 2A and 2.4A). For the sake of argument, let's ignore the voltage because it's not really relevant to this discussion (seeing as all the chargers give out 5V).

When using a 5W power supply to charge an iPhone, you will be drawing the maximum current available (1A). If you use a 10W, you'll pull the SAME amount of amps (still 1A), and with a 12W....do you get the point yet?

Two things limit the charging time of your device:

1. The MAXIMUM output of the charger
2. The MAXIMUM power draw of the device

If you are using the EXACT right charger (same voltage and ampage as the device) then it will draw the maximum amps/watts available. If you use a higher rated power supply you will STILL pull the same amount of amps/watts but it will no longer be the maximum amount the charger can put out. You will NOT charge your device any faster. A higher-rated power supply will NOT damage your device, because the device will only draw as much current (amps) as it needs. The charger will not force the little electrons into the device any faster than it can handle.

On the other hand, if you put a higher-rated device on a lower-rated charger you will get the following results:

1. Your device will take a LOT longer to charge. In fact, it may appear not to be charging at all. Experiment for yourself: plug a new iPad 4 into an old USB 1.0 or 2.0 port overnight and see how much charge you've gained in the morning.
2. You've heard of "trickle charge" right? This is where the current being fed into the internal battery isn't actually enough to properly charge the battery. The battery will be discharging power at almost the same rate at which it is charging. Yes, this will damage your battery over time. You saw it a lot in the original Nokia USB-charging phones - the batteries died after a few years and would no longer maintain charge. There's nothing wrong with doing this as a once-off, for emergencies, or on an irregular basis, but you will do progressive damage to your device if you keep doing this.

At home I have an iPhone 4, 4s, 5 and iPad 4. They all get charged off the same power pack - a 12W (5V, 2.4A) power block that came with my iPad 4. All of my devices charge, none of them have been damaged.

TLDR;

1. Using a higher-rated power supply on an iPhone won't damage it or charge it any faster.
2. Using a lower-rated power supply on an iPad will charge it very slowly and do progressive damage to the battery.

Moral to the story: buy a 12W charger and use it for all your devices to save carrying multiple chargers.

Answer (score 4):

As per the documentation on the Apple Store site:

> **[Apple 5W USB Power Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD810LL/A/apple-5w-usb-power-adapter)**
>   iPhones supported: Original, 3G, 3GS, 4, 4S, 5
>   iPods supported: Touch 1st-5th gen, some of the classic models, Nano 2nd-7th edition, Shuffle 2nd-4th edition
>   iPads supported: mini **(and none other)**

and:

> **[Apple 12W USB Power Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD836LL/A/apple-12w-usb-power-adapter?fnode=74)**
>   iPhones supported, iPods supported: Same as for 5W
>   iPods additional: Touch 1st gen, Nano 1st gen, A lot more of the classic models
>   iPads supported: mini, **1st-4th generation**

So while you can use the 12W charger to charge both iPhones and iPads, you can not use the 5W charger to charge the iPad, except for the mini.

**Note**: As others have suggested here, it may (seem to) work, but if you experience any problems, like a burnt out charger and/or iDevice, having used an unsupported combination is sure to put a dent in the warranty plan for the damaged unit.

**Note 2**: Since the two chargers sell for the same price on the Apple Store, if you have to buy one, buy the 12W charger.

Answer (score 0):

The official response to the "Can I..." question is yes.

However, here are the issues.  Using  5W charger on a device that requires a 10W charger, can and will damage the battery.  It produces what is called a "trickle charge" which drains as it charges.  Even when the iPad is turned off.  This leads the smart sensors in the cells to go haywire and not know when it is fully charged or not.  This often leads to people seeing their battery charge capacity lessen much faster over time.

The blocks used in the chargers are what regulate the wattage.  A 5W charger cannot produce the needed 10W to properly charge the  iPad, however, the iPd 10W charger, CAN and will regulate itself for the 5W device.

When combined with the proper components, this 10W charger usage on the iPhone, will not cause any damage or overheating in the phone, unless the device has already been damaged, typically via water/liquid.  (proper components: Apple Charging block, Apple USB/Lightning cable, and undamaged dock/lightning port)

With the lightning cable and the iPhone 5/iPad 4 this will also charge the iPhone 5 faster than the 5W block.  Added bonus.

EDIT: Sorry, the 10W is the "old" adapter (which BTW still works for the latest iPads) though they now deliver with a 12W adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. I am doing that quite often, and even though it takes longer to charge, for travelling, when I carry both my iPhone and iPad, it is nice to only carry the small iPhone charger.

Answer (score 0):

> If yes, what is the price of new charger in **India**?

You can find an [Apple Retailer](http://www.apple.com/in/buy/) in your area to get pricing on a new Power Adapter.

Answer (score -2):

It's not advised to charge the iPad 3rd Generation or 4th Generation with iPhone charger. I'm not sure of iPad 2.

The following is the power capacity of the chargers:
* iPhone -> 5 Watts or 1A
* iPad 3 -> 10 Watts or 2A
* iPad 4 -> 12 Watts or 2.4A

It's **not advisable** to use iPhone charger for iPad since it chunks out only half the required power. Eventhough it charges the iPad very slowly, overtime this might damage the battery. There are a lot many chances for this.

You may use your iPad 3/4 charger to charge your iPhone - this delivers express charging, but again this might damage the battery. I use express charging very rarely (only when i'm in a hurry) otherwise always use my iPhone charger or PC.

If you've got iPad 3, then you can get a iPad 4 charger to speeden up the charging.

Answer (score -3):

No, you can not do that.

http://gaffeycat.blogspot.com/2012/07/can-i-use-my-iphone-charger-with-my.html

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: That's a fun link. The title says "Can I use my iPhone charger with my iPad", the text is about a guy blowing up his iPhone by using an iPad charger. So I think the link isn't really that helpful...

Answer (score -3):

No the iPhone charger will burn out.
The iPad charger is best for iPad and iPhone charger is best for iPhone.